# PHP's filter_var, is it a good modern solution?

Tags: php

How reliable is `filter_var()`?  Do you find it useful?  Is it a good solution to validating a user's input?

Comment: This is a pretty subjective question... `filter_var` does one specific thing and only for a specific set of validations, so either it is useful for your specific application or it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have not yet used it in any projects, I have tried it out a bit and all of the filters that I tried seem to work very well - and its a lot more elegant a solution than the messy regexes that I currently use. I certainly think it is quite a useful function that I will definitely be using in the future.